# Algebra Word Problem - Distance between two towns

Tags: puzzle, word-problem

How would I find the answer to the attached question?

> A freight train is $27$ minutes late when it makes its usual trip between town A Trinhland and Town B Jafferton at an average speed of $56$ km/hr. For another trip between Town A and B, the freight train is $42$ minutes late when its average speed is $54$ km/hr. What is the distance between Town A and Town B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is an approach:
$d=v_1*t=v_2*(t+15/60)$
$v_1*t-v_2*t=v_2*0.25$
$t(v_1-v_2)=v_2*0.25$
$t = v_2*0.25/(v_1-v_2)$

$d=v_1*v_2*0.25/(v_1-v_2)$

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Distance =time *speed 
If time taken by train from place A to B = x hours
From case 1-- distance between A and B = 
56(x+27/60)
From case 2-- 
Distance b/w A and B= 54(x+ 42/60) 
From case 1 and case 2 
56(x+27/60)=54(x+42/60)
X=27*14/60
Put the Vale of x in case 1 
D= 56(27*14/60 + 27/60)
    =56*27*15/60
     = 378 km

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).